# Can we say there is High Bias if we have high training error due to small training data size?

Tags: machine-learning, bias, small-sample

If for a very small dataset we have a high training error, can we say that we are underfitting or have a high bias because of the low amount of training data?

Or do we use these terms (underfitting  and high bias) only for referring to issues due to low model complexity?

Comment: Small dataset --> high variance. Overly simple/inflexible model --> high bias. Yours is the first case.

Comment: @Richard But doesn't high training error signify high bias?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: Okay, wouldn't high variance come into picture if we were talking about high test error?  Also is there any resource you can point me to for understanding why high training error may not necessary signify high bias?

Comment: James et al. ["An Introduction to Statistical Learning"](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5ff2adbe3fe4fe33db902812/t/601cc86d7f828c4792e0bcae/1612499080032/ISLR+Seventh+Printing.pdf) has some material on the bias-variance trade-off and related stuff, so it could be helpful.

Comment: My source of confusion is this (not sure of the reliability): “If both, the training and test set error are high, then it symbolizes that the machine learning model has not properly learnt the input-output mapping on the training set and is also unable to generalize on the test set. … Such a model is said to underfit on both, the training and test dataset and suffers from high bias.” —  https://towardsdatascience.com/contents-9b2e49f49fe9

Comment: This is correct but is it relevant? As the sample sizes shrinks, variance grows regardless of whether bias is small or large. The way you have framed the question (small training sample, no mention of test sample) suggests the problem is variance. It is still possible that bias is high, too, but the result should hold regardless of the size of the bias.

Comment: On the other hand, all is relative. It is easier to tell the source of the problem when you vary something (the sample size or the model complexity) and observe how the results change. In your example, there is no variation, thus hard to identify the issue.

Comment: @DhruvMullick Suppose you estimate a ridge regression with an absurdly large regularization term. You can always choose a regularization which is large enough that the model coefficients are constrained to small values near zero. This model exhibits high bias, no matter what the size of the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bias and variance are not connected to your specific sample, but to the estimation method and the underlying distribution. The variance is most often connected to the sample size, however. High training error does not automatically signify high bias, high training error can be the result of low sample size.

If you have a point estimator, say the sample mean $\bar{x}$ for the distribution mean $\mu$, then the bias is the difference between the expected value of $\bar{X}$ and $\mu$. It can be shown that the expected value of $\bar{X}$ is $\mu$, and hence, the sample mean is an unbiased estimator of the distribution mean. If you are not used to providing mathematical proofs, you can think of it this way: What happens if your sample size grows towards infinity? Will the difference between your estimator and the parameter you are trying to estimate eventually become 0?

The variance of your estimator says something about how much you can expect your estimator to vary from sample to sample, and this is often used to say something about the uncertainty of your results. Back to $\bar{X}$ as an example: Say you have a sample that gave you $\bar{x} = 13.5$. If you took another sample of the same size, how much would you expect $\bar{x}$ to differ?

Because bias and variance are connected to the underlying distribution, in most cases you cannot know their exact values, but the theoretical results can help you choose an estimator with low bias and variance.

If you have a model that you are training for classification/prediction, the same principles apply.

Some models will give you zero training error if you add enough parameters (e.g. an n-1 polynomial for an n-sized training set), at the cost of huge variance. An unbiased model could give you training error if you simply do not have enough data to train the model (e.g. $n<p$), and you have to use some default parameters to fill in.

There are no universal results you can lean on, since "model" does not have a specific definition.